# How to install/activate logitech webcam c270 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: webcam, logitech

I do have an inbuiltwebcam in my laptop, but I ve bought one Logitech c270 for my college project purpose.
Everytime I m trying to open my externally added webcam, it starts the inbuilt webcam.
How to enable my external webcam in my laptop having ubuntu 18.04?? plse help

Comment: What does "trying to open ... webcam" mean? What program are you using?

Comment: I m trying to access the external wbcam using python openCV,.Webcam working properly with cheese but not creating frames in opencv

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your program.

I am like `cheese` f.ex. just install with:
`sudo apt install cheese`

Than take a look how it works with:
`cheese --help`
[...]
`-d, --device=DEVICE        Device to use as a camera`
[...]

(`--help` or `-h` should work with any program. If you're in any GUI search for 'Help' in the menu bar)

All possible devices can be seen with `ls -ltrh /dev/video*` and it starts with 0 (your internal cam). The external cam should be available with:
`cheese -d /dev/video1` (of course depending on the other system configurations)

- If this is too much, just disable the internal cam in your Laptop BIOS (the steps depends on your device).
- If you'd like to have a cool solution, may you'd like to write an `udev`-rule for the permanent reorder.
- Something in between is to find and unload the kernel driver ... but this needs to have two different camera chips/drivers. And when you'll start to write in `/etc/modprobe.d/` (for example in `blacklist`), it could be easier for us to support the `udev`-thing.

Comment: with cheese its working fine, Thanks for that..
Now I m trying to cv2.VideoCapture(1) with open cv to capture the video frames, it says it cant open camera with index 1...Later I checked the devide id,as 825, and used cv2.VideoCapture(825)..The error message doesnt say now it cant open cam with that index but instead it says it couldnot create any frames

Comment: I have no access to a OpenCV system right now. But I suggest you should add this in formation in the tags of this question and show us all the related code (better a little snipplet) and the exact output. So anybody can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't it be cv2.VideoCapture(0)?

Answer (score -2):

You can confirm with `lsusb` that it doesn't need to be installed.

On Ubuntu 21.04 I plugged the c270 Logitech camera in. Then checked that it was mounted:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b724 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated 
...
```

Then, in Zoom and Slack, in preferences and video set up it allows you to choose which camera from a pull down. In both programs, my camera was one of the choices.